# Add a prefix to all lines during execution of a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following bash script :

```bash
#!/bin/bash

output_names=("run1" "run2" "run3")

for name in "${output_names[@]}"; do
    ls | sed "s/^/[$name] /"
done
```

producing the following output :

```
[run1] f1.cpp
[run1] f2.cpp
[run2] f1.cpp
[run2] f2.cpp
[run3] f1.cpp
[run3] f2.cpp
```

It adds the text `[runX]` before each line produced by the command `ls`.

The issue I have is that the output is displayed when the process at the left of the `|` ends, and I would like it to be displayed on time of the execution (in practice, I do not want to run this script with `ls` but with an application that takes some times to run).

How could I update the code so during execution the display is done, with the prefix before each line ?

Comment: see `sed(1)`: _"-u, --unbuffered -- load minimal amounts of data from the input files and flush the output buffers more often"_ (from GNU sed manpage, Copyright © 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.  License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.        This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.  There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.)

Comment: yes thanks, I did not have the keyword "unbuffered"

Comment: You're welcome @Thomas. Keep in mind that with `|` you can only handle standard output, not standard error (unless you redirect it to standard output), but in bash `>(sed ...)` process substitution allows you to apply the a sed filter on different handles each.

Comment: thank for the precision. I'm acutally using this loop in a slurm script with the standard error redirected to a file, so I dont' think this will cause trouble at this level (but I may be wrong)

Comment: Ah yes, but no, I didn't mention because of any trouble, just in case you're looking for a way to filter both with sed. But I read you're already doing output redirecting like a pro, therefore I now shut up. Happy coding.